# Rails devise customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In devise's user table i'm trying to save email and password through a different controller , but in server log i'm getting this error ,

```
    WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: encrypted_password
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
     User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY       'mail@mail.com' LIMIT 1
    (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Added encrypted_password attribute to the model.

So i'm not able to insert it to users table.
And  ,How to  encrypt password? as devise gem has built in.

Controller :

```
  @user = User.new(:email => params[:supplier][:username],:username => params[:supplier][:username],:encrypted_password => '$2a$10$/Hh7UegsWm2ndRXbDEfjvOKBUiI1fa/z1GIbE5OYFpyqW6P97llsG')
  @user.save
  puts @user.errors
```

Model :
      attr_accessible :encrypted_password

Comment: you are using rails4?

Comment: have you ran `rake db:migrate` after installing devise?

Comment: No needed because i have installed devise already and its working perfect , what i'm doing is trying to add values to the devise's user table through a different model.So i guess rake db:migrate is not required here,correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: can you post the model code?

Comment: Updated to my question.Supposed to say controller , my bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use

```
user = User.new(email: "...", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save!
```

This way, devise will do the work for you, and you don't have to bother about confirmation emails. If you want confirmation emails still to be send out, remove the second line

Comment: But what about password encryption? How would i encrypt password like devise does.

Comment: And how to get rid of email uniqueness while updating record?

Comment: I don't understand why you would like to encrypt yourself? When updating record, email uniqueness won't be a problem. Just use update_attribute on a record, without touching the email or password.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, can you pls also accept it?  Thanks!